# Difference between variance threshold and VIF

Tags: python

I have come across a function in sklearn called `VarianceThreshold()`. Is this related to the `variance_inflation_factor()` function in statsmodels?

If they are different, what exactly is the difference between both the functions?

Answer (score 1):

`VarianceThreshold()` simply drops the features that don't vary much (or at all). VIF estimates multicollinearity by regressing a feature against other features (high VIF = a feature is well explained by other features).

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Cleared up a lot of confusion in my mind.

Answer (score 0):

The **variance threshold** is a simple baseline approach to feature selection. It removes all features which variance doesn’t meet some threshold. By default, it removes all zero-variance features, i.e., features that have the same value in all samples.

While on the other hand

The **variance inflation factor** is a measure for the increase of the variance of the parameter estimates if an additional variable, given by exog_idx is added to the linear regression. It is a measure for multicollinearity of the design matrix, exog